# .env file Flaged as not being an object when deploying trough DevOps CD pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I have just created a .env file to separate my environment variables from my main `docker-compose` file. I can run this document on my local machine fine with no errors or issues but when I try run it through my CD pipeline I get the following error.

> [error]Top level object in 'C:\BuildAgent_work\r38\a\"Myproject Name"\drop\ .env' needs to be an object not 'class 'str'.

I first thought this was because I had set up my build/CI process wrong but I have played around with it and have had no luck.

I have also done some research online to find others with the same problem but none relate to DevOps in anyway so it has been unhelpful

I am not sure how to reproduce this problem but if anyone knows I can try provide some of my code if needed

Edit:

Here is a snippet of my .env file. Check comment below for my thoughts

> ContainerInfrastructure_Version=6.7.93-beta.1
>
> ContainerInfrastructureCore_Version=6.7.41-beta.1
>
> AuthenticationWebService_Version=6.7.52-beta.1
>
> CRM_Version=6.7.52-beta.1

Expected result:

> Deploys successfully

What I'm getting during the docker-compose task:

> [error]Top level object in 'C:\BuildAgent_work\r38\a\Goldpine.ReleaseManagement\drop.env' needs to be an object not 'class 'str'.

Comment: I have just tried to remote into the domain and try run it there directly and it works fine with no issues so I assume it's has something to do with DevOps.

Comment: I have now tried to download the artefact that is create during the build phase and run that directly on the domain and I get no errors either. So I'm running out of things to try :(

Comment: Now that I think about it I think the problem is not with the file itself but what with the file. It says that some top leave object in .env needs to be an object so maybe their is something wrong there? I will try add a example of my code to see if anyone can see anything wrong

Comment: try to change `drop.env` to `.env`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. I'm not sure how to explain this briefly but I'll do my best.

So the problem was within DevOps itself not my code. It turns out a `.env` file only works/gets picked up if you run the docker-compose command from within the working directory that the `docker-compose.yml` file exists.

When it went into `DevOps` it was not running the command from within the downloaded artefact directory but by creating a path to it using the `-f` command.

So long story short, If you use a `.env` file you need to set the `working directory` within the `CD pipeline` to your artefact folder for it to be able to see the `.env` file correctlly.

I hope this is clear enough if not just let me know and I'll try change it accordingly :)